# Should I use different method names or overload parameters in Java?

Tags: java

I have come up with two different ways to implement a few methods in my class:

```
class Zoo {

    public void addTiger(Tiger tiger);
    public void addEmu(Emu emu);
    // ...
}

class Zoo {

    public void add(Tiger tiger);
    public void add(Emu emu);
}
```

The only difference between the two, that I can see, is verbosity - but am I missing something more fundamental? Will one approach make something more difficult in the future?

Comment: I've already posted the same question there: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132369/should-we-rename-overloaded-methods

Comment: What's wrong with doing both? `public void addTiger(Tiger tiger) { add(tiger); };`

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Double the methods... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the difference between adding a Tiger and adding an Emu? Why not make an Animal interface?

I would do something like:

```
class Tiger implements Animal { }

class Emu implements Animal { }

class Zoo {
    void add(Animal animal) { }
}

Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
zoo.add(new Tiger());
zoo.add(new Emu());
```

But there won't be a big difference in your two approaches, they are both equally right or wrong, since the violate the [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles.

Comment: Yes, I can agree with that - but assume for the sake of argument that they differ radically enough that two methods are required.

Comment: Then, dare I say it not, use a Visitor pattern? (ow, I said it!)

Comment: I haven't used the Visitor pattern before - if it's not too troublesome of a pattern, could you offer a `Zoo` example? If not, I'll read about it later and try to edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

If, in the future, you will decide to merge Emu and Tiger by making them both implement the same interface or extend the same class, and therefore merge the two methods, using

```
class Zoo {

    public void add(Tiger tiger);
    public void add(Emu emu);
}
```

will ease your job because you won't need to change anything in the places that use your method.
So yes, the first approach could make something more difficult in the future.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good point about merging methods in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Base on context that you'are using.

In this context, that Tiger and Emu both is Animal. I prefer using overloading method, it will make sense. And, if Tiger and Emu both inherit from Animal class. You can declare an array of animal:

```
Animal[] zoo;
```

and this zoo both contains Tiger and Emu. You can do this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < zoo.length; i++) {
    BigZoo.add(zoo[i]);
}
```

In OOP, we say this is polymorphism.

But, if those things are two different meaning. For example, A server has two things to add: `User` and `Data`. It makes sense :

```
addUser(User user);
addData(Data data);
```

rather than:

```
add(User user);
add(Data data);
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: I understand your first point, which others agree with, but you didn't offer any reasons for your second one. Why `addUser` instead of `add(User user)`?

Comment: @sdasdadas because `User` and `Data` object is different meaning. So, you can think this scheme : When you are reading `add(User user)`, and at later time, you reading `add(Data data)` you will think that both `User` and `Data` have some relationship. method name should tell clearly what they will do. It's a important point when you try to name a method. In first example, it's better if you name `addAnimal()` rather than just `add`